# Is it possible to return polygon bound or 3d image segmentation for a detected object with TensorFlow Lite and MLKit?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I am making a project that utilizes MLKit. The classification model will be a TensorFlow Lite model. I noticed that the detected objects always return rectangular bounding boxes. I would like them to return polygonal bounds that are shaped like the object it is detecting, or if possible, a sort of "3D" bound.

I am aware of certain annotation tools, along with things like Mask RCNN, but I am not sure how to integrate them into a TensorFlow Lite model (or if I am supposed to implement it in the model rather than the base code) or if I can even do it at all, hence why I am asking...

Is it possible to make the detected objects return bounding polygons, or even 3D polygons/image segmentations, instead of bounding boxes, using MLKit + TensorFlow Lite?

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit's Object Detection & Tracking API is limited to 2D bounding boxes for detected objects. I am personally not aware of generalized object detection solutions that return polygons as boundaries. Image segmentation (e.g. [Tensorflow Lite Image Segmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/segmentation/overview)) seems like an  easier approach, although you may need to (re-)train your own model depending on the application.